# Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 22 (LOAD_COMPONENT_FAILED)

Tags: terminal, chrome-os

I was trying to open the terminal (penguin) in my Chromebook, therefore I clicked on the icon. It loads for a few minutes and then gives out the following error:

```
Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 22 (LOAD_COMPONENT_FAILED)
```

I thought that maybe uninstalling and re-installing linux would do, but I have important files in the **Linux folder** which I am unable to back up as it is raising an error.

When I try to open the folder, it keeps on loading forever or just doesn't load. If I re-install Linux without backing anything up, I will lose my important files.

Answer (score 2):

I got the exact same error. Here are some fixes.

Simple:
Restart your chromebook and leave it off for a minute or two and turn on again or do that other thing to turn it off and on again(with the refresh and power button)

Check for updates(chromebook & linux)
Check about google chrome and update it

Advanced:
I didn't have to do this, but I think a good idea might be to check chrome://components/ and see if you need to update anything.

Use crosh(Ctrl Alt T ) and type vmc start termina and see if that works(I don't know the specifics though)

this helped me: It's not the exact same error(but it worked!): https://www.technipages.com/fix-chromebook-error-starting-penguin-container/

Last Resort:

Backup if you can.(You can't resize linux disk or backup once you get the error)
Wipe it. You'll lose all the data in your Linux Files so I guess have a backup next time

Hope this works!!!